# new column from existing panda dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file, which i have converted to a dictionary.
within the json file there are the what i call 'easy headings' of 'Year' and 'Category' which are standalone within the json file. 
The new column i want to create will be called 'awarded_or_not' and the data will be retrieved from entries within a dictionary headed 'Laureates' in the json file.

so far i have this to retrieve and print the two 'easy headings'...

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def report(nobelprizeDict):
  # convert dictionary to DataFrame
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nobelprizeDict)
  # select columns 'year' and 'category'
  res = df[['year', 'category']]
  # return result
  return res

with open('nobelprizes.json', 'rt') as f:
  nobel = json.load(f)

df_years_categories = report(nobel)

print(df_years_categories)
```

for example, if i were to write `res = df[['year', 'category', 'laureates']]` the 'laureates' component prints the whole entry list within the laureates dictionary into that column

i hope this makes sense and someone could correct it so i can see what i have done wrong

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: can you add a few examples of nobelprizes.json ?

Comment: maybe take a look at [pandas.io.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Comment: e['laureates'][0]  contains: [{'id': '976',
  'firstname': 'John',
  'surname': 'Goodenough',
  'motivation': '"for the development of lithium-ion batteries"',
  'share': '3'},
 {'id': '977',
  'firstname': 'M. Stanley',
  'surname': 'Whittingham',
  'motivation': '"for the development of lithium-ion batteries"',
  'share': '3'},
 {'id': '978',
  'firstname': 'Akira',
  'surname': 'Yoshino',
  'motivation': '"for the development of lithium-ion batteries"',
  'share': '3'}]   which information are you looking for. is it all of them?

Comment: You can get the json from http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json

Comment: but how you determine if was awarded or not ?

Comment: @opressionslayer thank you, the awarded or not (@GiovaniSalazar) is determined if there are no 'id' tags i believe, for example if you go to the json file above, 1972 category 'Peace'... there are no 'laureates' dictionary because no prize was awarded

Answer (score 1):

Here an example , I use numpy  to determine if laureates has a value or not , later added a column with value if laureates is True or False...notice that you add  nobelprizeDict['prizes'] (in my case):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def report(nobelprizeDict):
  # convert dictionary to DataFrame{}
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nobelprizeDict['prizes'])
  # select columns 'year' and 'category'
  res = df[['year', 'category', 'laureates']]
  return res

with open('nobelprizes.json', 'rt') as f:
  nobel = json.load(f)

df_years_categories = report(nobel)
df_years_categories['laureates'] = np.max(df_years_categories.isna(), 1).astype(bool)
df_years_categories['awarded_or_not'] = np.where(df_years_categories['laureates']==True, 'NO', 'YES')

print(df_years_categories)
```

Comment: I'm purposefully trying not to use numpy, going for deep problem solving techniques, but it's driving me up the walls! xD

Comment: but the code resolve your question ?...do you mean that not work ?

Comment: terminal is returning:
Traceback  (most recent call last):
file "2.11.py", line 15, in <module>
df_years_categories = report(nobel)
file "2.11.py", line 7, in report
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nobelprizeDict['prizes'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Try with pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nobelprizeDict) just....I Know part is different

Comment: I will put a version using url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204083/discussion-between-drleechy-and-giovanisalazar).